# Embedding images using CID refs with Outlook MailItem object not displaying in email

Tags: python, outlook, mailitem

Trying to use an Outlook signature through Python (using `3.10.6` for this example), however the images within the signature are not being displayed. Just shows the typical broken image with "The picture can't be displayed."

Here is what I am using to create the draft email, where `full_path_body_content` is the html signature text that's been previously modified to use absolute paths for all its image refs.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from lxml import html

outlook = Dispatch("outlook.application")
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = recipients
mail.CC = cc_recipients
mail.BCC = bcc_recipients
mail.Subject = subject

root = html.fromstring(full_path_body_content)
for img_tag in root.xpath("//img"):
    src = os.path.abspath(img_tag.get("src"))
    if not src.startswith("http"):
        attachment = mail.Attachments.Add(src)

        cid = str(os.path.basename(src)).split(".")[0]              
        attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", cid)

        img_tag.set("src", f"cid:{cid}")

modified_body_content = html.tostring(root, method="html", encoding="unicode")
mail.HTMLBody = modified_body_content

for attachment_path in attachments:
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment_path)

mail.Save()
```

So this works fine with creating the draft, adding my attachments, and displaying the text, but the images are all broken. If I simply remove the line `attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", cid)` then I do see the images actually attaching to my email draft in Outlook, and if I open the attachment I see the expected image just fine. So this means the part of adding the files from a path is correct, its just assigning the files CID to my body doesn't seem to be working.

I can confirm from debugging though that the `modified_body_content` does reference the CID images in the body. i.e. Within `modified_body_content` I can see that an `img` will have `src="cid:image002"` which should be correct.

During debugging I have also confirmed that the attachments do have the property properly assigned by checking `[attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F") for attachment in mail.Attachments]` which gives the following output for my images: `['image002', 'image004', 'image006', 'image008', 'image010']`.

So given that the images should attach fine, the CID is assigned properly for each image, and the body content properly references the CID in the `src`, I am at a bit of a loss.

Only other thing I can mention is that when I remove the `.SetProperty` line the images are attached as actual attachments I can see, and if I save the draft as HTML I can see the images in the files folder it creates. However when I do set the CID property, the images are not shown (as expected) but when I save the draft as HTML I do see it creates the files with appropriate width and height for the images I expect to see, but they're all black and 0 bytes in size. So maybe it isn't attaching them correctly, or maybe that's just expected output from embedded images.

**Edit**: Using OutSpy I was able to confirm the CID and attachments were properly linked.

Comment: What do you see for `HTMLBody` after the message is created and saved? Do `img` tags have the right values? You can check in OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy - I am it author): select the message, click Item button, select HTMLBody property. To see the attachment image tags, click IMessage button, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab, double on the attachment and look for the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENTID` property.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Using your program I see the html body and the images are using the cid like this `src="cid:image006"` and for that image if i go to the attachment table and view image006 i see it has PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID_W of image006

Comment: One thing i do find strange is that in my drafts if i look at the html body i see my email has 5 images and 1 pdf file, and an image is using say `cid:image006` for a picture. But if i actually send it to myself, and look at the message in my sent or inbox, i see it now has 10 images and 1 pdf, and where it previously had `src=cid:image006` it now says `src="cid:image009.png@01DA3A6D.15236B60"`. idk if that's just outlook doing its own thing during the sending process but additional info if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email signature I was using had VML formatting that my desktop application was trying to use over the img tags, whereas the web version must prefer img over VML. Never heard of VML before so didn't think much of it as I was trying to debug this. Ended up using regex:

```
re.sub(r'<!--\[if gte vml.*?-->', "", html_body_content, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

along with lxml

```
for img_tag in root.xpath("//img"):
    if 'v:shapes' in img_tag.attrib:
        del img_tag.attrib['v:shapes']
```

Which removes all the `v:shapes` attributes in my images and all of the if statements that try to display the VML. Embedded images now displaying perfectly.

Takeaway for anyone in similar position: Keep it simple. Test out a simple e-mail before complaining that a complex one doesn't work.